# How to open in a new tab in php where id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>

Tags: php

How to open a student details hyper link or button in a new tab. 
The link is

```
<a href="student_details.php?details_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
```

Comment: Honestly? This is "HTML 101" stuff and a simple Google search would not have killed you. The post is of very low-quality; IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `target` attribute with `_blank` value :

```
<a href="student_details.php?details_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"
   target="_blank"
   class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
```

Comment: Yes Thank you . Now this is working good. Thank you once again